# Can a tcp connection receive data from old stale tcp connection?

Tags: sockets, tcp, port, ipc, communication

I have a client server program, which written for IPC. Server and client processes are being connected to each other and both are following a fixed pattern of sending and receiving predefined data over socket (it is fixed when and what data will be communicated over socket at both end). The IPC works fine however I got below problem -

In a random run client process is receiving some unexpected data which can't be sent from server at that moment (the whole communication working as per expectation many times). After looking more inside, I found that when this problem was coming, some stale old server processes were running. When I killed all old processes, everything works fine and later on I never faced this issue.

Just curious to know what was exactly happening that time. I am inferring following  - 
A stale server process was earlier connected to client over port X. These server-client processes terminated unexpectedly and some data packet may alive in network. New server client processes are connected to each other but the new client is on same port X (how many chances of having this?). Now new client has received some packet of old server (packets which are left in network due to earlier connections of same port). All server client processes are on local machine so IP address will be same for each connection.

Is this possible to have this scenario which I explained above? Let me know if any doubt regarding query.

Comment: The random initial sequence number and the TIME_WAIT state are both provided to address this problem. Are you resetting connections instead of closing them properly? Or have you messed with the TIME_WAIT timeout?

Comment: What if process is terminated abruptly, will the TIME_WAIT still work? I am closing connections properly but not sure when process is being terminated forcefully.

Comment: It depends on whether the connection was closed properly or reset, which could happen if it was still open when the process aborted. It's platform-specific. If it was reset when it would normally have gone into TIME_WAIT if closed normally this could happen.